# Как разрешить команду пользователю при условии, что у него 2 определенные роли?

Tags: python, discord

Пытался сделать так, но не сработало.

```
@client.command(pass_context = True )
@commands.has_role("1" and "2")
```

Comment: что за библиотеку ты используешь?

Comment: Вот эти:  import discord
from discord.ext import commands

Comment: хм попробуй сделать

```python
if @commands.has_role("1") and @commands.has_role("2"):
    @client.command(pass_context = True )
```

Comment: К сожалению не получилось. Пробовал по разному вставить, но всегда выдавало  invalid syntax

Comment: сейчас напишу ответом, потому что в комментах нет форматирования

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаком с данной библиотекой, однако следующий код может сработать:

```py
if @commands.has_role("1") and @commands.has_role("2"): #если есть роль 1 И есть роль 2
    @client.command(pass_context = True)#выполняем нужную команду
```

Comment: (https://disk.yandex.ru/i/sAWwxYqWfXS2QA) Всё рано ошибка в if

Answer (score 0):

Я привёл просто пример с командой `test`, вы могли использовать декоратор `@commands.has_role()`, но там идёт проверка только на одну роль.

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    role_one = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild, id=ид_первой_роли)
    role_two = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild, id=ид_второй_роли)
    if role_one in ctx.author.roles and role_two in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.send('Работает!')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author}, у вас нет нужных ролей.')
```